# How to test a class which reads from a file

Tags: java, testing, interface, abstraction

I can a couple of classes defined by myself which are in charge of reading different shapes from different types of file (json, csv, xml) , and possibly later from a web service.

I have come up with a common interface called `ShapeReader`

```java
public interface ShapeReader{

    List<Shapes> readShapes() throws Exception;
}
```

I have a couple classes implement this interface

`FlatFileReader`

```java
public class FlatFileReader implements ShapeReader{

    private static final String filename = "shapes.txt";

    @Override
    public List<Shape> readShapes() throws Exception {

        List<Shape> shapes= new ArrayList<>();
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource(filename).getInputStream()))) {

            String line ;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                 
                 // create Shape objects
                
                );

                shapes.add(shape);
            }

            log.info("Items read from json file: " + items);

        }
   
        catch(Exception e) {
            //error handle
        }
        return shapes;
    }
}
```

`XmlReader`

```java
public class FlatFileReader implements ShapeReader{

    private static final String filename = "shapes.xml";

    @Override
    public List<Shape> readShapes() throws Exception {

        List<Shape> shapes= new ArrayList<>();
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource(filename).getInputStream()))) {

            String line ;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                 
                 // create Shape objects from xml
                
                );

                shapes.add(shape);
            }

            log.info("Items read from json file: " + items);

        }
   
        catch(Exception e) {
            //error handle
        }
        return shapes;
    }
}
```

I am not sure how I can even test this. I was thinking of reading from a mock test.txt file, but the filename is hardcoded as a static constant. What is the best way to solve this issue which I assume is poor design

Comment: Pass the filename as a parameter so it's not fixed? Actually, I'd suggest passing an `InputStream` so you can also handle URLs and such.

Comment: but I am anticipating that I will need to retrieve these Shapes from a web service at some point, so I would have to add the filename argument to the interface, which would also mean the web service will implement this method accepting a filename as argument

Comment: *"but I am anticipating that I will need to retrieve these Shapes from a web service at some point"* Then why you dont separate the conversion of the file content into a new class that you can inject into both, the `FlatFileReader` and the future `WebServieReader`? This separate conversion class would be easy to test.